# How to make android layout background transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Make android layout background transparent]

How to make `RecyclerView` item background transparent I need to show background image?

I tried 3 solutions given in **Stack Overflow** and not worked for me

```
1 : android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"<br>
2 : android:background="@android:color/transparent"<br>
3 : alpfha 0.4
```

udated i also tried 
4: android:background="@null" (Answer from this post) and not working

[full xml code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11jxqngGIv3COfVGsSj7dlY3iAiNnQOsGUrXrWpJlFAI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for the layout?

Comment: i am sorry , when i try to add code stackover showing "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 31496.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Yea can you just post the relevant section, just the xml for the view that you are trying to make transparent

Comment: updated please check it

Comment: You should try to separate your xml into separate files so it is more modular and maintainable.  Many views have @null backgrounds so they won't have a background shown

Comment: how to make layout with imageview and name and there background as transprent

Comment: So the background of android:id="@+id/ads_text" is not @null even though the linear layout is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071813/7579041 this may help you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to give this on your item `CardView`

```
 app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: How to set this programmatically?

Comment: cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.transparentColor));

or

cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**1)      In your manifest make that activity theme to Transparent-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidhub4you.transparent.background"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidhub4you.transparent.background.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.transparent"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**2)      Now your page will be 100% transparent, so if you need some background color then set opacity like-**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#80000000"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

So for the layout you are inflating for the item you can use 
`android:background="@null"`

You can also use developer options on your device to see layout bounds or check the view hierarchy to see which item is giving you problems

Answer (score 0):

First add this style in styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

then add this line in AndroidManifest.xml below the corresponding activity

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

set all layout `backgrouncolor= '#00000000'` also to your `Recycleview` background color to achieve this view

Answer (score 0):

set transparent color  in your view

#80000000